# facing invalid session id while excecuting the webdriver two times in one scenario

Tags: dart, testing, automation, webdriver, bdd

I am trying to execute one scenario to test,in that I am executing webdriver two times but while execution of 2nd time of webdriver facing invalid session id issue. Following is the code -
Scenario:

```
Scenario: Validation of Delete access functionality for single patient
    Given I navigate to the 'DashboardView' screen with 'partner_006' user name and 'Minimed@1' password with patient 'patientCardTile_0'
    Then I verify that the 'patientCardListItemText_0' title has text: 'Tim Pane'
    And Open chrome Desktop and Log in with 'patient_006' user name and 'Minimed@1' password in Carelink
    And I click using attribute 'xpath' on element with locator '//*[@id="h-data-sharing"]/span' in Chrome
    And I click using attribute 'xpath' on element with locator '//*[@id="cpm-remove-care-partner"]/span' in Chrome
    And I click using attribute 'xpath' on element with locator '//*[@id="mat-dialog-0"]/app-modal-confirm/div/div[2]/button[1]' in Chrome
    And I close the webdriver
    When I tap 'menuButton' button
    When I tap 'myDashboardButton' button
    And Open chrome Desktop and Log in with 'patient_006' user name and 'Minimed@1' password in Carelink
    And I click using attribute 'xpath' on element with locator '//*[@id="ch-notifications-icon"]/img' in Chrome
    And I click using attribute 'xpath' on element with locator '//*[@id="mat-dialog-0"]/app-notifications-snackbar/div[2]/button' in Chrome
    And I click using attribute 'xpath' on element with locator '//*[@id="cp-approve-request"]/span' in Chrome
    And I close the webdriver
```

Following are the Step definations of BDD steps only webdriver related ones-

```
class LoginWithChromeDesktop extends Given2WithWorld<String, String, CPATWorld> {
  static final _log = Logger('chrome_desktop.dart.|Tap');
  @override
  Future<void> executeStep(String userName, String password) async {
    final driver = WebDriverFactory.getDriver(); // Get the WebDriver instance
    await login(userName, password, driver);
  }
  Future<void> login(String userName, String password, WebDriver driver) async {
    try {
      // No need to create a new WebDriver instance here
      // Use the driver passed as an argument
      final chromeCapabilities = Capabilities.chrome;
      await driver.get('https://carelink-stage3.minimed.eu/');
      sleep(const Duration(seconds: 10));
      // Find and interact with web elements as needed
      final continueButton = await driver.findElement(const By.xpath('/html/body/app-root/app-country-and-lang/div/div/div[2]/form/a'));
      await continueButton.click();
      final userNameID = await driver.findElement(const By.cssSelector('#username'));
      userNameID.sendKeys(userName);
      final passwordID = driver.findElement(const By.cssSelector('#password'));
      passwordID.sendKeys(password);
      final loginButton = await driver.findElement(const By.xpath('//body/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/form[1]/div[3]/input[1]'));
      await loginButton.click();
      sleep(const Duration(seconds: 10));
    } finally {
      // Do not quit the driver here;
    }
  }
  @override
  RegExp get pattern =>
      RegExp(r'Open chrome Desktop and Log in with {string} user name and {string} password in Carelink');
}

class AndClickUsingAttribute extends And2WithWorld<String, String, CPATWorld> {
  @override
  Future<void> executeStep(String attribute, String locator) async {
    final driver = WebDriverFactory.getDriver();
    // Use the passed locator
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator)).click();
    sleep(const Duration(seconds: 5));
  }
  @override
  RegExp get pattern =>
      RegExp(r'I click using attribute {string} on element with locator {string} in Chrome');
}

class AndCloseWebDriver extends AndWithWorld<CPATWorld> {
  @override
  Future<void> executeStep() async {
    final driver = WebDriverFactory.getDriver();
    // Close the WebDriver instance
    driver.quit();
  }
  @override
  RegExp get pattern => RegExp(r'I close the webdriver');
}
```

Webderiver .dart for the driver creation and closing -

```
class WebDriverFactory {
  static WebDriver? _driver;
  static WebDriver getDriver() {
    if (_driver == null) {
      final chromeCapabilities = Capabilities.chrome;
      _driver = createDriver(
        uri: Uri.parse('http://localhost:4444'),
        desired: chromeCapabilities,
      );
      // Maximize the WebDriver window
      _driver!.window.maximize();
    }
    return _driver!;
  }
  static void closeDriver() {
    if (_driver != null) {
      _driver!.quit();
      _driver = null;
    }
  }
}

Facing error - 
And Open chrome Desktop and Log in with 'patient_006' user name and 'Minimed@1' password in Carelink # C:\Users\ZMO-WIN-PreetiM-01\Documents\CarePartner\care-partner-app\test_features\android\CPAP006_patient_deleted_access_screen\cpap006_patient_deleted_access_screen_01\cpap006_patient_deleted_access_screen_01.feature:26 took 44ms  
InvalidSessionIdException (404): invalid session id
```

And is it possible that without closing the driver can I continue the execution on the same driver?